# Prism and Xamarin Forms: Navigation to native views (Android, iOS, UWP)

Tags: navigation, xamarin.forms, prism, native

Is there a way in Prism for Xamarin Forms to navigate from a Xamarin Forms page to a native view (like an activity on android etc.)? Is this even possible?

Say I have a Xamarin Forms page with a button, if I click the button, I want to go to a Activity1 on Android. The activity has another button to get back to the Xamarin Forms Page.

Btw. if I use Prism are there tradeoffs, like some things I can't use from Xamarin Forms when I use Prism or so?

And does somebody have a good documentation for Prism? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a Prism question.  This is more of a "is there a way to navigate to a native view in Xamarin.Forms" type of question.  While I would always recommend having XF handle the navigation, and would challenge your decision to navigate to a native view, it is possible.  You will have to enlist the help of custom renderers to do it.  See this post for code samples: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/104598#Comment_104598

EDIT: To answer your other questions, there are no tradeoffs.  Prism does not prevent you from using any of the XF features.  It simply abstracts away services so that they can be used within a VM.  In some cases you actually get better and more rich features with Prism over XF.  As with most free open source projects, docs are limited but can be found here: http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks Brian!
I want to use Xamarin.Auth, which brings its own views. That's the reason for me wanting to navigate to a native view. Maybe there is another way to do this, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a PageRenderer